# Get folder size

Tags: java, file-io

Do you know how can I get the folder size in Java?

The length() method in the File class only works for files, using that method I always get a size of 0.

Comment: What do you expect the folder "size" to be?  The actual size of the folder in the file system or the size of all of the files within it?

Answer (score 28):

Use apache-commons-io, there's a `FileUtils` class with a `sizeOfDirectory` methods

Comment: Warning, this method has a serious issue where it can throw an IllegalArgumentException while running. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-389

Comment: The bug that @Fhl mentioned has been fixed from version 2.5 of the commons-io library.

Comment: @Ozuf Can you please link to the changelog/source? Thanks

Comment: @Fhl it is there in the link that you pasted above.

Answer (score 21):

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class FolderSize
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    long size = FileUtils.sizeOfDirectory(new File("C:/Windows/folder"));

    System.out.println("Folder Size: " + size + " bytes");
   }
}
```

Comment: This method has a serious issue. It can throw an IllegalArgumentException while aggregating the file sizes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-389

Comment: The bug that @Fhl mentioned has been fixed from version 2.5 of the commons-io library.

Answer (score 7):

```
import java.io.File;

public class GetFolderSize {

    int totalFolder = 0;
    int totalFile = 0;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String folder = "C:/GetExamples";
        try {
            GetFolderSize size = new GetFolderSize();
            long fileSizeByte = size.getFileSize(new File(folder));
            System.out.println("Folder Size: " + fileSizeByte + " Bytes");
            System.out.println("Total Number of Folders: "
                + size.getTotalFolder());
            System.out.println("Total Number of Files: " + size.getTotalFile());
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public long getFileSize(File folder) {
        totalFolder++;
        System.out.println("Folder: " + folder.getName());
        long foldersize = 0;
        File[] filelist = folder.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
            if (filelist[i].isDirectory()) {
                foldersize += getFileSize(filelist[i]);
            } else {
                totalFile++;
                foldersize += filelist[i].length();
            }
        }
        return foldersize;
    }

    public int getTotalFolder() {
        return totalFolder;
    }

    public int getTotalFile() {
        return totalFile;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a slight error with simply recursively iterating over all subfolders.  It is possible on some file systems to create circular directory structures using symbolic links as is demonstrated below:

```
mkdir -- parents father/son
ln -sf ${PWD}/father father/son
ls father/son/father/son/father/son/father/son/
```

To guard against this error, you can use the java.io.File#getCanonicalPath method.  The code below is a slight modification of a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169394/281545).

```
public static long getFileSize(File folder) throws IOException {
    return ( getFileSize ( folder , new HashSet < String > ( ) ) ) ;
}

public static long getFileSize(File folder, Set<String> history)
        throws IOException {
    long foldersize = 0;
    File[] filelist = folder.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < filelist.length; i++) {
        System.err.println("HISTORY");
        System.err.println(history);
        boolean inHistory = history.contains(filelist[i].getCanonicalPath());
        history.add(filelist[i].getCanonicalPath());
        if (inHistory) {
            // skip it
        } else if (filelist[i].isDirectory()) {
            foldersize += getFileSize(filelist[i], history);
        } else {
            foldersize += filelist[i].length();
        }
    }
    return foldersize;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over all subfolders in the folder and get the summary size of all files there.

Answer (score 0):

Folders generally have a very small "Size", you can think of them as an index.

All the programs that return a "Size" for a folder actually iterate and add up the size of the files.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DirectorySize {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          // Prompt the user to enter a directory or a file
          System.out.print("Please Enter a Directory or a File: ");
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          String directory = input.nextLine();

          // Display the size
          System.out.println(getSize(new File(directory)) + " bytes");
   }

   public static long getSize(File file) {
           long size = 0; // Store the total size of all files

           if (file.isDirectory()) {
                  File[] files = file.listFiles(); // All files and subdirectories
                  for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                         size += getSize(files[i]); // Recursive call
               }
           }
           else { // Base case
                  size += file.length();
           }

           return size;
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Go through a folder, file by file, getting the size of each file and adding them to the variable size.

```
static int size=0;

 public static int folderSize(File folder){

    size = 0;

    File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();

    for(File file : fileList){
        if(!file.isFile()){ 
            folderSize(file);
        }
        size += file.length();
    }
    return size;
}
```