# Android, Fast and efficient way of finding a directory size?

Tags: android, file

In my app, I want to find the size of many directories and I need it run fast. I have seen these methods, two of which are not fast enough and the third is just for Java, not Android.

## First:

```
public static long folderSize(File directory) {
long length = 0;
for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isFile())
        length += file.length();
    else
        length += folderSize(file);
}
return length;
}
```

## Second:

[Using Apache FileUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169396/9600898)

## Third:

[Using Java 7 nio api, which doesn't work in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19877372/9600898)

What other fast and efficient way is there to be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java get file size efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116574/java-get-file-size-efficiently)

Comment: It is also a Java question. Can't be applied to Android. Also it is about file size, not a directory size. @ShubhamSrivastava

Comment: The question I pointed to is a Java Question.

Comment: Using the `.length()` on the directory file object should give you the size in bytes.

Comment: No it's not convenient at all! It mostly returns a fixed amount of 4 KB!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using kotlin

```
val size = File(parentAbsolutePath,directoryName)
                .walkTopDown()
                .map { it.length() }
                .sum() // in bytes
```

Comment: Finally some kotlin, and a good solution

Answer (score -1):

### Use `StatFs` to get a lightning-fast estimate of a directory size.

We tried using `du -hsc` and we tried using Apache `FileUtils` but both were far too slow for large and complex directories.

Then we stumbled upon `StatFs` and were blown away by the performance. It's not as accurate but it's very very quick. In our case, about 1000x faster than either `du` or `FileUtils`.

It appears to be using the stats built into the file system to get the estimated directory size. Here's the rough implementation:

```
// Wicked-quick method of getting an estimated directory size without having to recursively
// go through each directory and sub directory and calculate the size.
//
public static long getDirectorySizeInBytes( File directory ) {
    if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2 ) return 0; // API < 18 does not support `getTotalBytes` or `getAvailableBytes`.

    StatFs statFs = new StatFs( directory.getAbsolutePath() );

    return statFs.getTotalBytes() - statFs.getAvailableBytes();
}
```

Comment: NOTE: `StatFs` appears to only get the disk usage of the entire partition or drive, not a single directory.

Comment: Please clarify can I use this function for a specified directory or not.

Comment: @CyberAvater No. Jus the entire partition or drive.